# Javascript to grab parts of the URL

Tags: javascript

I've looked through tons of great posts on pulling query string parameters, and even using regex to grab parts of the URL path. But, it didn't really answer what I'm trying to do.

I need to be able to grab the current URL a user is on and parse out only parts of the pathname, and capture them into separate variables. I don't care about the query string parameters I only want these key parts.

```
http://www.domain.com/part1/part2/part3/part4

var1=part1
var2=part2
var3=part3
var4=part4
```

My Javascript is a bit rusty, so any guidance on this would be great!

Comment: Use `str.split('/')`

Comment: `location.pathname.split("/").slice(1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As users in the comments mentioned, the url string is no different than any other string. You can easily just use the string split method to return an array of strings between the `/` character

To get the href location you can use `window.location.href` or `location.href`

`var url_str = window.location.href;`

The `str.split()` function takes a separator parameter in this case `'/'` and returns an array of strings that were found. For example it would return this given your example url `http://www.domain.com/part1/part2/part3/part4`:

`var arr = url_str.split('/');`

`["http:", "", "www.domain.com", "part1", "part2", "part3", "part4"]`

The array `.slice(begin,end)` method returns a portion of the array from the `begin` to `end`(default end of the array) parameters (both zero based, first element = 0, 10th = 9).

To get the last 4 parts of our example array we do the following:

`var values = arr.slice(3);`

`["part1", "part2", "part3", "part4"]`

Now you can either access the array directly to get each value or assign them to variables:

`console.log("Your first folder is "+values[0]); //direct access`

or

```
var var1 = values[0];
var var2 = values[1];
var var3 = values[2];
var var4 = values[3];

console.log("Your first folder is " + var1]); //variable alias
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution will split up your string using the slash as a separator, ignoring the protocol.

```js
var url = "http://www.domain.com/part1/part2/part3/part4"
var parts = url.split('/').splice(2);
console.log(parts);

var baseUrl = parts[0];
var part1 = parts[1];
var part2 = parts[2];
var part3 = parts[3];
var part4 = parts[4]
```

Comment: And this will grab it dynamically regardless of the protocol. In other "part1" could change to "bob1" and this syntax would still grab it. Or, if everything is dropped but "part1" it would still grab it based on the split separator?

Comment: Basically, yes. If `url` was `ftp://domain.biz/foo$/bar*`, `parts` would be `["domain.biz", "foo$", "bar*"]`.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to get the url parts like you want.

```js
var url = "http://www.domain.com/part1/part2/part3/part4"
var parts = url.match(/.+w{3}\.\w+\.\w{3}\/(\w+)\/(\w+)\/(\w+)\/(\w+)/);
console.log(parts);

var baseUrl = parts[0];
var part1 = parts[1];
var part2 = parts[2];
var part3 = parts[3];
var part4 = parts[4]
```

But again, as cyberbit and Patrick have mentioned, you can simply do url.split('/') to get the parts. That way you don't have to worry about how many parts you get in the url. Thanks.